# Strange issue with SQL contains - ignoring starting characters of a string

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am experiencing a strange issue with the sql full text indexing. Basically i am searching a column which is used to house email addresses. Seems to be working as expected for  all cases i tested except one!

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CONTAINS(Email, '"email@me.com"')
```

For a certain email address it is completely ignoring the "email" part above and is instead doing

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CONTAINS(Email, '@me.com')
```

There was only one case that i could find that this was happening for. I repopulated the index, but no joy. Also rebuilt the catalog.

Any ideas??

**Edit:**
I cannot put someone's email address on a public website, so I will give more appropriate examples. The one that is causing the issue is of the form:

```
a.b.c@somedomain.net.au
```

When i do

```
WHERE CONTAINS(Email, "'a.b.c@somedomain.net.au"')
```

The matching rows which are returned are all of the form `.*@somedomain.net.au`. I.e. it is ignoring the `a.b.c` part.

Comment: show us the data / a simple 'non' working example please.

Comment: Does `WHERE Email LIKE '%email@me.com%'` work? Also, if you're looking for an exact value, why not just compare it using the equals operator (`WHERE Email = 'email@me.com'`)? And in you first example, you have both single and double quotes, why?

Comment: Example added. And yes the like operator works fine. And I may be looking for an exact value but the column is a list of email address separated by a semi-colon.

Comment: The `CONTAINS` keyword is used to *search columns containing character-based data types for precise or fuzzy (less precise) matches to single words and phrases, the proximity of words within a certain distance of one another, or weighted matches*. Do you really need all those features? If you don't, use the `LIKE` keyword (which you've mentioned works as you expect).

Comment: Yes. LIKE performs terribly here, and I cannot index it since it is an nvarchar(max) column! I understand what you are saying, if LIKE works then use that instead. But I am more interested in *why* it is not working with the CONTAINS operator.

Comment: If you're able to confirm that the problem occurs with this particular user name, no matter what domain they're at, there shouldn't be an issue with posting the address as `a.b.c@example.com`. If the problem disappears if you use a different domain, that's an interesting piece of the puzzle to add also. It's highly likely that it's the *specific* characters in this email address that are causing the issue, so giving us examples (which may be closer or farther from the actual value than we may expect) may not be helping.

Comment: Hi Damien, the problem does not seem to associated with the domain. However i will do more thorough tests! Thanks.

Comment: Check if it will search on A.B.C alone.  I suspect that is not a valid word or it is a stop word.

Comment: Yep, it will not work with `CONTAINS(Email, 'a.b.c')`.

Comment: I suspect a.b.c are being parsed into separate words and none alone are valid words.  Period is typically a word break character but in an email it is not.

Comment: @Blam is correct. The full-text engine invokes an external word breaker which splits a sentence into words which are then indexed. In this case, 'a.b.c' is likely being word-broken into 'a', 'b' and 'c' which are then stored in the internal index. Are you limited to SQL 2005? If not then there are a couple of DMVs you can use to verify this behavior.

Comment: Thanks guys. And yes I am limited to SQL 2005. Is it possible to override this behaviour? I thought when the string is wrapped in double quotes it should search for the whole word/string?

Answer (score 2):

Full stops are treated as noise words (or stopwords) in a fulltext index, you can find a list of the excluded characters by checking the system stopwords:

SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords WHERE language_id = 2057 --this is the lang Id for British English (change accordingly)

So your email address which is "a.b.c@somedomain.net.au" is actually treated as "a b c@somedomain.net.au" and in this particular case as individual letters are also excluded from the index you end up searching on "@somedomain.net.au"

You really have two choices, you can either replace the character you want to include before indexing (so replace the special characters with a match tag) or you remove the words/character you which to include from the Full Text Stoplist.

NT// If you choose the latter I would be careful as this can bloat your index significantly.

Here are some links that should help you :

[Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

[Create Full Text Stoplists](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280405.aspx)

Comment: Seems like the view/table `fulltext_system_stopwords` is for 2008 onwards. Any 2005 versions. I think in the end I will just replace the full stop then with something else. Thanks!